# Simple Photo Gallery Image Formatting Tool

Tags: c#, performance, winforms

I created a little tool to help me take a folder of images and convert them into a properly formatted structure for a photo gallery I'm working on. This includes keeping the original high res photo, and making a smaller version for previewing.

A gallery with 260 images takes 11,631ms on my laptop and a gallery with 10 takes about 450ms. Is there anything I can do to make this code more efficient?

Note: All photos that are sent to me for the photo gallery are a JPEG.

MainForm.cs

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PhotoGalleryFormatter
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        private string    _originalDirectory;
        private string    _outputDirectory;
        private string    _galleryName = "formatted-gallery";
        private string[]  _originalFiles;
        private Stopwatch _timer;

        private const double DownscaleRatio = .35;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize Form
        /// </summary>
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _timer = new Stopwatch();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Opens FolderBrowserDialog to select original directory to work with
        /// </summary>
        private void OpenFolderBrowserDialog()
        {
            using (var dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog())
            {
                var result = dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK;
                if (result && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dialog.SelectedPath) )
                {
                    _originalDirectory = dialog.SelectedPath;
                    _outputDirectory = _originalDirectory + @"\formatted-gallery\";
                    txtFileDir.Text = _originalDirectory;
                    txtOutputDir.Text = _outputDirectory;
                    _originalFiles = Directory.GetFiles(dialog.SelectedPath, "*.jpg");
                }

                btnFormat.Enabled = result;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Auto-Generates a output directory based on gallery name
        /// </summary>
        private void CalculateOutputDirectory()
        {
            if ( !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtGalleryName.Text) )
            {
                _galleryName = txtGalleryName.Text;
                _galleryName = _galleryName.Replace(' ', '-');
                _outputDirectory = _originalDirectory + @"\" + _galleryName + @"\";
            }
            else
            {
                _galleryName = "formatted-gallery";
                _outputDirectory = _originalDirectory + @"\formatted-gallery\";
            }

            txtOutputDir.Text = _outputDirectory;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Formats gallery file names
        /// </summary>
        private void FormatGallery()
        {
            _timer.Start();

            if( Directory.Exists(_outputDirectory) )
                Directory.Delete(_outputDirectory);

            if ( Directory.Exists(_outputDirectory + @"\preview") )
                Directory.Delete(_outputDirectory + @"\preview");

            Directory.CreateDirectory(_outputDirectory);
            Directory.CreateDirectory(_outputDirectory + @"\preview");

            for (var i = 0; i < _originalFiles.Length; i++)
            {
                if ( File.Exists(_originalFiles[i]) )
                {
                    var path = _galleryName + "-" + (i + 1) + ".jpg";
                    File.Copy(_originalFiles[i], _outputDirectory + path);
                    CreatePreviewImage(path);
                }
            }

            _timer.Stop();
            MessageBox.Show("Gallery " + _galleryName + " has been formatted in " + _timer.ElapsedMilliseconds + "ms.",
                            "Gallery Format Complete", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            _timer.Reset();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Resizes image for preview folder
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="path">Path of image</param>
        private void CreatePreviewImage(string path)
        {
            using (var originalImage = Image.FromFile(_outputDirectory + path))
            {
                using (var resizedImage = DownsizeImage(originalImage))
                {
                    resizedImage.Save(_outputDirectory + @"preview\" + path, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Downsizes image to preview size using _downscaleRatio
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="image">Original un-scaled image</param>
        /// <returns>New downsized image</returns>
        private Image DownsizeImage(Image image)
        {
            var newWidth  = (int) (image.Width  * DownscaleRatio);
            var newHeight = (int) (image.Height * DownscaleRatio);
            var newImage  = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);

            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
            {
                graphics.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
            }

            return newImage;
        }

        private void btnLoadDir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFolderBrowserDialog();
        }

        private void txtGalleryName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CalculateOutputDirectory();
        }

        private void btnFormat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormatGallery();
        }
    }
}
```

MainForm.Designer.cs

```
namespace PhotoGalleryFormatter
{
    partial class MainForm
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(MainForm));
            this.btnLoadDir = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.txtFileDir = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.gbFileInfo = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
            this.btnFormat = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.lblOutputDir = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.txtOutputDir = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.lblOriginalDir = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.txtGalleryName = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            this.lblGalleryName = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.gbFileInfo.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // btnLoadDir
            // 
            this.btnLoadDir.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 7.8F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.btnLoadDir.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 188);
            this.btnLoadDir.Name = "btnLoadDir";
            this.btnLoadDir.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(196, 38);
            this.btnLoadDir.TabIndex = 0;
            this.btnLoadDir.Text = "Load Directory";
            this.btnLoadDir.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.btnLoadDir.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnLoadDir_Click);
            // 
            // txtFileDir
            // 
            this.txtFileDir.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 7.8F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.txtFileDir.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(9, 48);
            this.txtFileDir.Name = "txtFileDir";
            this.txtFileDir.ReadOnly = true;
            this.txtFileDir.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(409, 22);
            this.txtFileDir.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // gbFileInfo
            // 
            this.gbFileInfo.Controls.Add(this.btnFormat);
            this.gbFileInfo.Controls.Add(this.lblOutputDir);
            this.gbFileInfo.Controls.Add(this.txtOutputDir);
            this.gbFileInfo.Controls.Add(this.lblOriginalDir);
            this.gbFileInfo.Controls.Add(this.txtGalleryName);
            this.gbFileInfo.Controls.Add(this.lblGalleryName);
            this.gbFileInfo.Controls.Add(this.txtFileDir);
            this.gbFileInfo.Controls.Add(this.btnLoadDir);
            this.gbFileInfo.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 7.8F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.gbFileInfo.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
            this.gbFileInfo.Name = "gbFileInfo";
            this.gbFileInfo.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(424, 238);
            this.gbFileInfo.TabIndex = 2;
            this.gbFileInfo.TabStop = false;
            this.gbFileInfo.Text = "File Info";
            // 
            // btnFormat
            // 
            this.btnFormat.Enabled = false;
            this.btnFormat.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 7.8F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.btnFormat.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(222, 188);
            this.btnFormat.Name = "btnFormat";
            this.btnFormat.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(196, 38);
            this.btnFormat.TabIndex = 8;
            this.btnFormat.Text = "Format Gallery";
            this.btnFormat.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.btnFormat.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnFormat_Click);
            // 
            // lblOutputDir
            // 
            this.lblOutputDir.AutoSize = true;
            this.lblOutputDir.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 7.8F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.lblOutputDir.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 140);
            this.lblOutputDir.Name = "lblOutputDir";
            this.lblOutputDir.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(112, 17);
            this.lblOutputDir.TabIndex = 7;
            this.lblOutputDir.Text = "Output Directory";
            // 
            // txtOutputDir
            // 
            this.txtOutputDir.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 7.8F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.txtOutputDir.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 160);
            this.txtOutputDir.Name = "txtOutputDir";
            this.txtOutputDir.ReadOnly = true;
            this.txtOutputDir.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(412, 22);
            this.txtOutputDir.TabIndex = 6;
            // 
            // lblOriginalDir
            // 
            this.lblOriginalDir.AutoSize = true;
            this.lblOriginalDir.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 7.8F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.lblOriginalDir.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 28);
            this.lblOriginalDir.Name = "lblOriginalDir";
            this.lblOriginalDir.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(118, 17);
            this.lblOriginalDir.TabIndex = 4;
            this.lblOriginalDir.Text = "Original Directory";
            // 
            // txtGalleryName
            // 
            this.txtGalleryName.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 7.8F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.txtGalleryName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(9, 105);
            this.txtGalleryName.Name = "txtGalleryName";
            this.txtGalleryName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(409, 22);
            this.txtGalleryName.TabIndex = 3;
            this.txtGalleryName.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.txtGalleryName_TextChanged);
            // 
            // lblGalleryName
            // 
            this.lblGalleryName.AutoSize = true;
            this.lblGalleryName.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 7.8F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.lblGalleryName.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(6, 85);
            this.lblGalleryName.Name = "lblGalleryName";
            this.lblGalleryName.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(94, 17);
            this.lblGalleryName.TabIndex = 2;
            this.lblGalleryName.Text = "Gallery Name";
            // 
            // MainForm
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(8F, 16F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(234)))), ((int)(((byte)(234)))), ((int)(((byte)(234)))));
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(447, 262);
            this.Controls.Add(this.gbFileInfo);
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
            this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));
            this.MaximizeBox = false;
            this.Name = "MainForm";
            this.Text = "Photo Gallery Formatter";
            this.gbFileInfo.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.gbFileInfo.PerformLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnLoadDir;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtFileDir;
        private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox gbFileInfo;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnFormat;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblOutputDir;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtOutputDir;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblOriginalDir;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox txtGalleryName;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblGalleryName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Copy and then read from file seems like extra work.  Read the image, downsize then save to a new directory.  Delete directory seems kind of reckless.

Comment: @Paparazzi The reason I delete it is because I don't want a duplicate. However, asking if the user wants to overwrite would be a better solution.

Comment: Are the files on your hard drive?  Why do you need to copy the original?

Comment: @Paparazzi Files start out on a hard drive. I plan to have it upload to a server instead of copying itself in the next iteration.

Comment: I still think you are doing extra work read it, copy original,   process, then copy processed.

Comment: @Paparazzi What do you think would be a better way to go about it? I'm open to ideas. Edit: misread that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this doesn't help with time but does help with code simplicity

> ```
>     private void CreatePreviewImage(string path)
>     {
>         using (var originalImage = Image.FromFile(_outputDirectory + path))
>         {
>             using (var resizedImage = DownsizeImage(originalImage))
>             {
>                 resizedImage.Save(_outputDirectory + @"preview\" + path, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

you only need to indent once here and use a single set of brackets, like this:

```
private void CreatePreviewImage(string path)
{
    using (var originalImage = Image.FromFile(_outputDirectory + path))
    using (var resizedImage = DownsizeImage(originalImage))
    {
        resizedImage.Save(_outputDirectory + @"preview\" + path, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }

}
```

you could also put both resources into a single using statement as @Vogel612 suggests in his comment, like this:

```
private void CreatePreviewImage(string path)
{
    using (var originalImage = Image.FromFile(_outputDirectory + path), 
            var resizedImage = DownsizeImage(originalImage))
    {
        resizedImage.Save(_outputDirectory + @"preview\" + path, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }      
}
```

Just make sure that the resources are in the right order.

---

you should always be in the habit of deleting the child folder before the parent folder.  I would switch these around:

> ```
> if( Directory.Exists(_outputDirectory) )
>     Directory.Delete(_outputDirectory);
>
> if ( Directory.Exists(_outputDirectory + @"\preview") )
>     Directory.Delete(_outputDirectory + @"\preview");
> ```

you should change the incrementation variable to start at 1 instead of 0 because you are using it for naming purposes only, I would also use string interpolation, (*I assume that you are going to be using C# 6+*), all of this makes assigning the path look like this:

```
var path = $@"{_galleryName}-{i}.jpg";
```

personally I would change this to a foreach loop though, and it would look like this instead (*I wasn't thinking about the numbering system...*).

```
int i = 1;
foreach(var file in _originalFiles)
{
    if (File.Exists(file))
    {
        var path = $@"{_galleryName}-{i}.jpg
        File.Copy(file, _outputDirectory + path)
        CreatePreviewImage(path);
        i++;
    }
}
```

I don't know off the top of my head if this will increase the speed of going through the files or not, but I would definitely check it out to see.

***random thought***

I have issues with the numbering system because then the pictures will have a weird sort by default in most folder viewing applications, once you hit 10 they sort weird and if everything has the same creation date you can't sort it.

---

you should look into using String Interpolation, it makes a lot of your string concatenation look so much cleaner.

this:

```
_outputDirectory = _originalDirectory + @"\" + _galleryName + @"\";
```

becomes this:

```
_outputDirectory = $@"{_originalDirectory}\{_galleryName}\";
```

When needing backslashes in the string you need to include the @ symbol, [order is important.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32508711/1214743)

Comment: Don't forget to use `$@` before string for `_outputDirectory` since backslash means escape sequence without @.

Comment: Really good answer. I had no idea about string interpolation until now. Also about your random thought, I'm formatting these for an already existing photo gallery on a website. I just used the same scheme as the original developer. Thank you though.

Comment: thank you @Maxim, I completely forgot about the Backslashes causing issues....

Comment: N.B. that you can collapse the double `using` into a single one. C# supports multiple resources in one using-statement and will clean them up in the correct order.

Answer (score 5):

You copy to disk then read from disk

```
File.Copy(_originalFiles[i], _outputDirectory + path);

var originalImage = Image.FromFile(_outputDirectory + path)
```

Read to memory, copy to disk, load the image from memory. It saves a read from file.

[Image.FromStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think of that, I'll try it out. Good call

Answer (score 4):

Just small note about combining path parts. You should never combine them manually with backslashes. There is the `Path.Combine` method and you should always use it.

Instead of

> ```
> _outputDirectory = _originalDirectory + @"\" + _galleryName + @"\";
> ```

you should write

```
Path.Combine(_originalDirectory, _galleryName);
```

Instead of

> ```
> _outputDirectory + @"\preview"
> ```

write

```
Path.Combine(_outputDirectory, "preview")
```

And here

> ```
> File.Copy(_originalFiles[i], _outputDirectory + path);
> ```

write

```
File.Copy(_originalFiles[i], Path.Combine(_outputDirectory, path));
```

Comment: After doing some testing I've found that they run about 20% slower but the Path.Combine really helps make the code look better so I think it's worth it. Thank you.

Comment: `Path.Combine` is something more than just strings concatenation. You can look at the source code of this method on [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/path.cs,2d7263f86a526264). As you can see the method perform checks on invalid chars, utilize path separators and takes care about these separators at the end of each string.